# Formatting string with padding

Tags: python, string, format, padding

I am trying to replicate this string:

[image]

This is what my attempt looks like, as you can see the values are not aligned correctly. I know I need to use some type of padding but everything I've done has failed.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
individual_text = '''
Highest Individual Question Scores
        •       Leaders
                •       {}{:.2f}
                •       {}{:.2f}
                •       {}{:.2f}
        •       Colleagues
                •       {}{:.2f}
                •       {}{:.2f}
                •       {}{:.2f}
Lowest Individual Question Scores
        •       Leaders
                •       {}{:.2f}
                •       {}{:.2f}
                •       {}{:.2f}
        •       Colleagues
                •       {}{:.2f}
                •       {}{:.2f}
                •       {}{:.2f}
'''.format(top_3_leader.index[0], top_3_leader.values[0],
           top_3_leader.index[1], top_3_leader.values[1],
           top_3_leader.index[2], top_3_leader.values[2],
           top_3_colleague.index[0], top_3_colleague.values[0],
           top_3_colleague.index[1], top_3_colleague.values[1], 
           top_3_colleague.index[2], top_3_colleague.values[2],
           bottom_3_leader.index[0], bottom_3_leader.values[0],
           bottom_3_leader.index[1], bottom_3_leader.values[1],
           bottom_3_leader.index[2], bottom_3_leader.values[2],
           bottom_3_colleague.index[0], bottom_3_colleague.values[0],
           bottom_3_colleague.index[1], bottom_3_colleague.values[1],
           bottom_3_colleague.index[2], bottom_3_colleague.values[2]
          )
```

How do I format my text to look like the 1st image?

Comment: I'd suggesting using `\t`

Comment: Maybe `Texttable` with no decorations? https://pypi.org/project/texttable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is task for `ljust` method of `str`, consider following example:

```
x = [('text',1.14),('another text',7.96),('yet another text',9.53)]
for i in x:
    print(i[0].ljust(25)+"{:.2f}".format(i[1]))
```

Output:

```
text                     1.14
another text             7.96
yet another text         9.53
```

There also exist `rjust` adding space at beginning rather than end.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify one constant length for first element in each row:

```
individual_text = '''
                •       {:40}{:.2f}
                •       {:40}{:.2f}
'''.format('some_text', 3.86,
           'text_with_another_length', 3.85,
          )
print(individual_text)

# output:
#               •       some_text                               3.86
#               •       text_with_another_length                3.85
```

You can calculate this length in some way like this:

```
import itertools

minimum_spaces = 3
length = minimum_spaces + max(len(item) for item in itertools.chain(
    top_3_leader.index, top_3_colleague, bottom_3_leader, bottom_3_colleague
))
```